# get unique id from indexeddb index

Tags: indexeddb

In indexed db I have following records

```
Key               Value
emp_1             { emp_fName : "Mike",
                    emp_lName : "Davis",
                    dept_id   : 1
                  }

emp_2             { emp_fName : "Merry",
                    emp_lName : "Bond",
                    dept_id   : 1
                  }
```

I have created index on dept_id, I want to fetch unique dept_id, how can I do that?

Comment: Hello User 780611! Thanks for asking an IDB tagged question. I see you haven't yet accepted any answers for questions you've asked but have the sufficient karma. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers I would definitely appreciate a "correct" answer if your needs are met below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a [cursor](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-cursor) on an index by using `openCursor()` or `openKeyCursor()` on an IDBIndex object. An example from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/):

```
var tx = db.transaction("books", "readonly");
var store = tx.objectStore("books");
var index = store.index("by_author");

var request = index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only("Fred"));
request.onsuccess = function() {
  var cursor = request.result;
  if (cursor) {
    // Called for each matching record.
    report(cursor.value.isbn, cursor.value.title, cursor.value.author);
    cursor.continue();
  } else {
    // No more matching records.
    report(null);
  }
};
```

A specific flag you'll want to set as your `IDBCursorDirection` is [`nextunique`](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#idl-def-IDBCursorDirection.nextunique) (vs. the default, `next`), which "should not yield records with the same key, but otherwise yield all records, in monotonically increasing order of keys."

Comment: It means that we have to do processing on resultset. From indexed db we can not get unique Id directly. Is that true?

Comment: It's indeed possible to get a key directly, either using the so-called "primary key" (always present) or an additional index. We call it an "exact key cursor" and it's still a cursor because you may have multiple entries under the same key. Look at the `getKey()` and `get()` methods. [Here's an example from my library that handles all cases.](https://github.com/buley/dash/blob/dee65c53619b7163612a4402566e1c6522e6a310/lib/dash.dev.js#L1252)